# JQuery .live event with asp.net causing error

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am trying to use jquery for dynamic content in asp.net.  The following code gives me an error.

Code:

```
    $(".NumericOnly").live('keydown', function (evt) {
        alert('test');
    });
```

Error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

The control:

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMerchandiseRegisnumAN" Class="NumericOnly" Text="" MaxLength="11" ></asp:TextBox>`

I can get it to work if I do a normal keydown event, but that doesn't work with dynamic content.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Figured it out.  The jquery code was in a user control, but other sections of the page had their own references to 1.2.6 versions of jquery, which didn't have the live() functionality.  I removed one and updated another and it is working!  Thanks for the help troubleshooting this!

Answer (score 2):

Use `CssClass` not `Class` (or take a look at the output and notice that it's not there)

Comment: +1 nice catch! I'll bank on that being it. Always look at your markup!

Comment: Nope.  Tried CssClass and got the same error.  With using just Class, the control looks like this, which shows it has the class assigned: `<input name="ncServiceInfo$ncHacienda$txtMerchandiseRegisnumAN" type="text" value="5678901234" maxlength="11" id="ncServiceInfo_ncHacienda_txtMerchandiseRegisnumAN" title="enter the Merch Reg No (note: this field must be an 11 digit value)" Class="NumericOnly" />`

Answer (score 1):

The `live()` function is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+. Instead try:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.NumericOnly', function (e) {
    alert('test');
});
```

`live()` was deprecated because it was known to cause a lot of problems. Maybe this will fix it.

Comment: Nope, downloading 1.7, and referenced it on the page and still no luck.  I even took an example straight from the jquery .on() page:          

$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function (event) {
      alert($(this).text());
});

I get the same error.  You may ask, well that control doesn't exist.  It doesn't have to.  I can do a bind with no errors:

$("#dataTable tbody").bind("click", "tr", function (event) {
    alert($(this).text());
});

Comment: Run `$().jqeury` from the JS Console and check what version is actually running. There is something very strange going on if you aren't able to bind an event to the `document`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      $("#<%=txtMerchandiseRegisnumAN.ClientID%>").live('keydown', function (evt) {
       alert('test');
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if jquery is loaded properly.  I've experienced this problem before and it usually was because jquery wasn't loaded.

you can check by adding this javascript code

```
if (jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
}
```

Comment: It's loaded, because I can change the live keydown event to a regular keydown event and everything works fine.  It just won't handle dynamic content.

Comment: @user1130587 What version of jQuery are you using?  I think .live was added at some point and if you have an old version it might not work